# How to pass an array of powershell to a python script

Tags: python, powershell, parameters, logic

I am actually trying to give an arrayList (System.Collections.ArrayList) in a powershell script to a python script like this :

Powershell script

```bsh
    $exampleArray= New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $tabChemins.Add("test1") | Out-Null
    $tabChemins.Add("test2") | Out-Null
    $tabChemins.Add("test3") | Out-Null
    python.exe .\exampleScriptPython.py $exampleArray
```

Python script : (I don't want to cycle through all the elements using a loop to create my list.)

```
    import sys
    print(sys.argv[1])
    print(sys.argv[2])
    print(sys.argv[3])
```

It gives me element by element but I want them in only one element, Output :

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Ideal output :

```
['test1','test2','test3']
```

Comment: How about `print(sys.argv[1:])` then? i.e., values are passed in fine, your problem seems to be in the way you print them (and I guess a few other things that you might wanna do with them).

Comment: Thank you @goodvibration it works ! I ask this question because I have multiple arguments to pass in my real powershell script but I think I will just put the array at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can simply use the array `sys.argv[1:]` for whatever it is that you want to do.

And if you want to pass it to a function as separate arguments, then I believe that `*sys.argv[1:]` would do the job.